# Safari compatible CSS3 Animation on an SVG element

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I've got a strange bug I can't seem to figure out:

I want to combine two CSS animation properties (opacity & transform: translate), and my target is an inline SVG element.

The combo is perfect in Chrome, fidgety in Firefox, and doesn't work in Safari.

Safari seems only capable of doing one or the other, not both at the same time. No idea what happens in IE at the moment as I'm on a Mac.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/712xwmss/

If anyone can help get it working smoothly across all 4 browsers it'd be greatly appreciated.

SVG:

```
<svg width="28" height="65" viewBox="0 0 28 65" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="center-block svgscroll">
<title>Example</title>
<g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M5 44.7l7 6.953 7-6.953" class="svgarrow sa1" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    <path d="M3 50.66l9 8.94 9-8.94" class="svgarrow sa2" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</g>
```

CSS:

```
    .svgarrow {
  -moz-animation: drop 1s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: drop 1s infinite;
  animation: drop 1s infinite;
}
.svgarrow.sa1 {
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.svgarrow.sa2 {
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@-moz-keyframes drop {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes drop {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(4px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(4px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using? I am on version 9, and it seems to animate perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi there, I'm on Safari v 8.0.6 (10600.6.3)

Comment: Safari Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17) - same broken behaviour on SMIL in SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Safari, It is fixed on latest version.

[Latest Safari version for Mac](http://www.apple.com/es/safari/)

[Safari 5.1.7](http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe) (Windows)